# How is 80 to 150 days to Mars possible at 6 km/s TMI Delta V?

Tags: spacex, mars, hohmann-transfer

Is the data presented on this slide realistic? Here's the slide:

[image]

Here's the talk at the time the slide is presented, so you can hear what he's saying with it.

I can not wrap my head around these numbers. Is there a known published source that could confirm these specific launch windows with extraordinarily low trip times? SpaceX is claiming trip times as low as 80 days, and this is with 6 km/s, with some of that reserved for landing (looks about 1 km/s, for 5 km/s for TMI). They are planning to launch from LEO, so we would have to credit some Oberth effect.

The reason I ask is because of the immense gulf between these numbers and what known sources say. To quote one, [150-300 days](http://www.universetoday.com/14841/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-to-mars/). The standard transfer calculations, which I can reproduce, [give 8.5 months](http://www.phy6.org/stargaze/Smars1.htm). That number is certainly overly conservative due to the elliptical orbits, but I've seen some give 6 months as the *best case* scenario. Even on this site, one answer seems to say that getting 2.5 months [would fundamentally destroy the economics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/why-not-travel-to-mars-in-2-months).

Should this be looked as something discrediting of SpaceX's ambitions? Or is there a realistic set of numbers where this could actually work? If I take the claims (and the background) at face value, it looks like it's a completely and totally impossible. Or is there something this evaluation is missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My [Hohmann spreadsheet](http://clowder.net/hop/railroad/Hohmann.xls) shows TMI from LEO is around 3.6 km/s.

[Here](http://clowder.net/hop/railroad/NonHohmannEarthToMars.xlsx) is a Non Hohmann transfer sheet from earth to Mars. Into the pink cells I type .9 A.U. for the transfer orbit's perihelion and 1.6 km/s into the transfer orbit's aphelion. Here's a pic of this transfer orbit:

[image]

This trip is about 140 days from earth to Mars.
TMI from LEO is about 5.2 km/s
Exiting Hohmann to enter low Mars orbit takes about 3.5 km/s. I am guessing Musk wants to most of the delta V at the Mars end of the trip via aerobraking.

All my spreadsheets assume circular, coplanar orbits. Of course Mars gets closer than the 1.52 A.U. my models assume -- Mars perihelion is 1.38 A.U. So trips can be shorter than what my spreadsheet indicates.

Comment: Surprising! Looks like your evidence points in the direction of "credible". FWIW, they claim 382 s specific impulse. If I plug this in for your exhaust velocity and point the Delta V to "Insertion burn from periapsis", then propellant per unit mass ratio is 3.18, aligning very closely with the 3-4 refueling launches also cited in the presentation.